# How to unzip a bunch of files using 7z on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, 7-zip

I'm using 7z to unzip files, e.g:

`7z x -p"PASSWORD" chr_1.zip`

However, I've got a bunch of files with the extension .zip. How do I unzip them all in one go??

I've tried googling, and can't find an answer to extracting a group of files in one go

Comment: https://youtu.be/BLnj4YIijgQ?t=117

Answer (score 1):

It's

```
7z x -p"PASSWORD" \*.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I needed to unzip individual files across a large hierarchy after a ransomware attack.
Here's my bash script for mac os, generated with ChatGPT. It unzips files in place and deletes the 7z. file afterwards.

```
#!/bin/bash

password="YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE"
yes_flag="-y"

function unzip_7z {
  for file in "$1"/*; do
    if [ -d "$file" ]; then
      unzip_7z "$file"
    elif [ ${file: -3} == ".7z" ]; then
      echo "Extracting: $file"
      if 7z x "$file" $yes_flag -p"$password" -o"$(dirname "$file")"; then
        echo "Deleting: $file"
        rm "$file"
      fi
    fi
  done
}

unzip_7z .
```